# How to prove or disprove if $a_n \leq M$, for some number $M$, then $L \leq M$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So here is the problem I am having a bit of trouble with. Not exactly sure how to approach this problem.

> Given the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ for some number $L$. If $a_n \leq M$ for all $n$, where $M$ is some finite number, prove or disprove $L \leq M$.

I am thinking about using a Proof by Contraposition. So, if $L > M$, then $a_n > M$.

Since we are told that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$, then we can say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n > M$. But this is where I am lost or do not how to proceed. I am not exactly sure how to get rid of the limit on the left side.

Some advice or some suggestions would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a proof by contradiction.

Let us suppose that $L > M$. Then, for $\varepsilon = (L - M)/3 > 0$, there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow  L - \varepsilon < a_{n} \leq M
\end{align*}

Hence we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
L - M \leq \varepsilon \Rightarrow \frac{2(L - M)}{3} \leq 0 \Rightarrow L \leq M
\end{align*}

which is a contradiction, and we are done.

In fact, for any constant $0 < k < 1$, the choice $\varepsilon = k(L - M)$ works.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Assume that $L>M$ and let $L-M=\epsilon$

than use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit for given $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

An idea for you: suppose $\;L>M\implies L-M=\epsilon>0\;$ . Then there exists $\;N\
\in\Bbb N\;$ such that

$$n>N\implies |a_n-L|<\frac\epsilon2$$

But remember that if $\;a>0\;$ , then for some real number $\;x\;,\;\;|x|<a\iff -a<x<a\;$ . Use this and the above to get your contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You prove: $L \le M$. Assume otherwise, then take $\epsilon = \dfrac{L - M}{2}>0$, then you will reach at some point a contradiction. Hope this helps. Note that the $2$ at the denominator can be adjusted to fit the need of the contradiction proof. So maybe you want to use $\epsilon = C(L - M)$, and you adjust $C$ to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Assume that $ L>M$.

take $$\epsilon=L-M$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=L \implies$$
for $ n $ great enough,
$$L-\epsilon<a_n \implies$$
$$L-(L-M)<a_n\implies$$

$$M<a_n$$

Which contradicts the hypothesis $ a_n\le M$.